# Speed up C code running USB webcam

Tags: webcam, c

I have some code that I have adapted to run on a headless Rpi using a usb webcam, it is running a bit slow, so my questions are:

- If I were to use the GPI pins with a dedicated webcam would that be faster?
- Is there any way to speed up my code for Rpi?
- Were can I get a Rpi webcam?

[My code is here, I struggle to paste inline so its a link](http://pastebin.com/mrqW0Bhq)

I wait in breathless anticipation for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at adding a 2nd network port via GPIO and found was not too fast.
Some people use the USB instead of the SD card as the interface is faster between arm and usb chip than the arm and the gpio/sd interface.

You know the new Pi camera board has been released, 60fsp, HD

Comment: Is the camera board for sale yet? Sounds really fast

Comment: @peterretief tried to order one yesterday, current delivery estimate for the camera is about 12 weeks.